# Schedule an E-mail before 24 hours based on users timezone

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a requirement to generate emails just before 24 hours of database date.I'm saving all the dates to database in UTC format and also registered users are from different time zones.So how can I write a query to fetch records just before 24 hours to send an email to users based on their respective time zones.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "just before 24 hours"? Before _what_?

Comment: And you want to take a look at a "queuing system" or "queue management system". Such solution basically processes task entries in a database by checking for due jobs on a periodic base.

Comment: Basically I need a query to get records from some x table which are having 24 hours time difference with respect to user timezone

Comment: @arkascha just before 24hrs means x table createdDate records difference with current datetime.

Comment: I suggest you compute the difference between your and the users time zone, then use mysql'd data functions to calculate a comparison in your query.

Comment: Actually every date am saving into database is in UTC format.So can't I directly query? just to know

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `TIMESTAMP` data types, not `DATETIME` data types. `TIMESTAMP`s are always stored in MySQL in UTC time.
2. When you establish a session for a particular user, set the user's time zone with a SQL command like `SET time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata';` before storing or retrieving `TIMESTAMP` values. They will be translated automatically to the current time zone when retrieved from your table. Likewise, they'll be translated to UTC when stored.
3. You can find records using queries like `SELECT something FROM table WHERE ready_time >= NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR` and use the result sets to send emails or do whatever you like.

I don't know how you will determine your user's time zone setting. Many systems make it a user preference. But you will need to obtain it in [tz database format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Actually we are providing a drop down to an user to select his timezone.When a record is getting inserted into any table we are saving it in UTC format.Just we are using timezone to display dates.